# How to programmatically change spinner item name at a given position android

Tags: android, android-studio, adapter, android-spinner, android-adapter

I would like to programmatically change a name of one of my spinner item but I am not sure how I can do this.

For example given the code below

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
         R.array.spinner_list_item_array,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I would like to

```
Change spinner ITEM name at position 1 to "NEW TEXT"
```

Comment: chnage adapter data at 1 position and call adapter.notifydataset()

Comment: You could create your own adapter, change the data, then notifydatasetchanged (or similar). There are plenty of tutorials about custom adapters. Do you want your change to propagate into R.array.spinner_list_item_array?

Comment: @Divyesh How? please show

Comment: first change data in your array and then call notifydatasetchnaged()

Comment: @el_chupacabra I just want to change name of position 1 item programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the data in `R.array.spinner_list_item_array`.

After you have changed the data you will need to then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and then `adapter.setAdapter(adapter)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 CharSequence[] fiilliste = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinner_list_item_array);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, fiilliste);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        fiilliste[1] = "NEW TEXT";
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks it it possible to change spinner text color in java?

Comment: Yes it is:create text.xml in your layout:

paste below code in it
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</TextView>

change adapter

 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, R.layout.text, fiilliste);